# Using ensure_sibling_para results in Origin error

Tags: xcm, xcmp

Using the following line results in the error 'Bad Origin' in Runtime call.

```
let para = ensure_sibling_para(<T as Config>::RuntimeOrigin::from(origin.clone()))?;
```

I am building a pallet that sends XCM-encoded calls (Like a ping pallet) to another chain. However, the mentioned line always gives me the error Bad origin. What am I doing wrong? I am using sudo accounts as the origin (Alice/Bob). I even tried to use sudo with a sudo account.

Answer (score 0):

Both `ping` and `pong` extrinsics of `cumulus-ping` pallet expect to be called by a sibling chain. In other words, it needs to be triggered by an XCM transact instruction that comes from any sibling parachain (see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/parachains/pallets/ping/src/lib.rs#L105)). So if you are calling `ping` or `pong` as an extrinsic with normal (that is not a sovereign account of sibling para) account, it won't work.

To start sending ping messages to other parachain, use `start` or `start_many` calls.